# PowerShell find and replace with regex in file behavior

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to find and replace a connection string with PowerShell. Here is the regex: https://regex101.com/r/onyJZz/1 finding what I need.

The content of the config file I want to modify looks like this:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="FrameworkEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PortalEntities.csdl|res://*/PortalEntities.ssdl|res://*/PortalEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
       provider connection string=&quot;data source=someservername.domain.co;initial catalog=Portal;persist security info=True;user 
id=user;password=user$ecurity;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Basically the whole value for connection string  needs to be replaced. Here is the gist of what I'm doing

```
$regex = '(?<=\bconnectionString=")[^"]*'
$dbname = 'newserver.domain.co' 
$user = 'sa'
$password = 'password2'
$catalog = 'Portal'
$frameworkdbpath = 'c:\folder\db.config'

$finalString = "metadata=res://*/PortalEntities.csdl|res://*/PortalEntities.ssdl|res://*/PortalEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=$dbname;initial catalog=$catalog;persist security info=True;user id=$user;password=$password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"

(Get-Content $frameworkdbpath) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace $regex, $finalString
} | Set-Content $frameworkdbpath
```

When running the above code the replace only works up to the first semicolon. The rest of the string remains and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string is wrapped across multiple lines. `Get-Content` returns the content as an array of lines, each of which is processed separately. Because of that the second and third line of your connection string are not matched by your expression.

**Bad solution:** Read the file into a single string before applying the regular expression. You can also remove the `ForEach-Object`.

```
(Get-Content $frameworkdbpath -Raw) -replace $regex, $finalString |
    Set-Content $frameworkdbpath
```

**Good solution:** Your input data is XML, so it should be processed as such.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $frameworkdbpath
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/connectionStrings/add')
$node.connectionString = $finalString
$xml.Save($frameworkdbpath)
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I'm sorta new at ps, I should have read the man page of get-content, I'l use the xml type and functions from here.

Comment: Why is the first method considered to be a bad solution?  Say you're matching on something presumably unique like `.*name="foo".*`.

Comment: @alex For very simple expressions that would probably work, yes. However, consider a situation where the XML document contains more than one node with a property "name", where nodes are wrapped across multiple lines, or multiple nodes are on the same line. Tackling XML data with regular expressions gets *very* complex *very* quickly, and it's not even possible in general, b/c XML is a type-2 language whereas regex is a type-3 language in the Chomsky hierarchy.

Comment: @alex Problems already start with the fact that in XML `name="foo"` is the same as `name = "foo"` is the same as `name='foo'`.

Comment: FTR: [DO NOT parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171). ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Fair point - sounds like it depends on your use case. Thanks!